# Rails / SASS: Undefined operation

Tags: ruby-on-rails, math, sass

I am converting parts of my stylesheet from pixels to percentage, but I keep getting this error, if I try to use several operations:

```
height:$height/3 * 2;
```

I also tried:

```
height:($height/3) * 2;
```

But keep getting this error message:

```
Undefined operation: "85, 7142857%/2, 10526316/3 times 2".
```

Whats wrong ? - I have bourbon installed as a gem.

Variables:

```
$inner_width:85,7142857%;  /* 1200 / 1400 */
$height:$inner_width / 2,10526316; /* 1200 */
```

Comment: Please add the definition of `$height` for completeness.

Comment: I put in in the orig. question..

Comment: Well... `$inner_width` isn't numeric--what should "85, 7142857%" divided by two look like? It's substituting exactly what you're telling it to.

Comment: Thanks.. I am not quite sure I follow..  why isn't the variable $inner_width nummerical ? - I wanted the height to have a relation to the width, so that everything scales proportional..

Comment: I think the problem is that I used ',' instead of '.' right ? it works if I change it (from comma to period)

Comment: That would be more numeric, certainly--it probably doesn't assume I18N properties for those places that use `,` as the floating point separator.

Answer (score 1):

Write your decimals with a dot. :) (Sass, like CSS, uses `.` for numbers and `,` for lists.)

```
$ sass --interactive
>> $inner_width: 85.7142857%
85.71429%
>> $height: $inner_width / 2.10526316
40.71429%
>> $height/3 * 2
27.14286%
```